# Determine best fit with regex

Tags: regex

I'm trying to create a mechanism that could determine how good a string matches, and determine the best fit. For example:

**Input**:

```
AAAB, AACS, BBBB, ZZZZZ
```

**4 rules**:

1. AA*
2. AAA*
3. BB*
4. *

**Output**:

```
AAAB -> 2, AACS -> 1, BBBB -> 3, ZZZZZ -> 4
```

Is it possible to determine this with regex?

Comment: Regex cannot determine what fits 'better', it can only determine what fits. You would have to compare each string to multiple regexs and score it for each one is successfully matches.

Comment: What you want to achieve seems kind of similar (but not exactly the same) to calculation of [Levenshtein Distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance). Have a look at that wikipedia link. You might find it interesting.

Comment: Any updates? Or did one of the answers below help you?

Comment: Hej Chris, 
I forgot to check my own answer - it's not the most beatifull solution but it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hej, 
I've created the following code.

First I replace all special characters, then I check if it's a match, when it is a match I've to determine how big the match is, I do this by counting the remaining characters beside the * character.

```
 public Int32 GetMatchQuota(string d)
    {
        Int32 retval = -1;
        string regMask = String.Format("^{0}$", Destination.Replace(".", "\\.").Replace("*", ".*").Replace("%", "."));

        if (Regex.IsMatch(d, regMask, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
        {
            retval = regMask.Replace("*", string.Empty).Length;
            if (!regMask.Contains("*") || !regMask.Contains("%"))
            {
                retval += 1;
            }
        }

        return retval;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as a 'best-fit' regular expression. If you want speed, the only thing you can do is benchmark the different regexes and see which one(s) are the fastest.

**UPDATE:**
After seeing what you really want. This cannot be done with regex, this needs to be done using the usual logic.

Answer (score 0):

Not with a regex.  It will only be a match or not.  There's no concept of a 'better' match.  However, if you know your regular expressions beforehand, you can determine which regexes are more strict.

Just check if there's a match for each one, then pick the strictest match.  In terms of your example:

`2 > (1 = 3) > 4`

If `2` ever gets a match, it's the best-fit.  `1` and `3` can never match the same thing, but they are equally strict.  `4` is the least strict and thus will only be the best-fit if it's the only match.

Answer (score 0):

From your examples, it looks like you just want to find the most specific one that fits.

I would suggest creating a list of regexes in ascending order of specificity, and run multiple passes over your test cases. The first regex that succeeds will be the "best fit".

In the examples you gave, you could order your regexes as follows:

1. BB*
2. AAA*
3. AA*
4. *

Then for, say, test case AACS, you would see that it doesn't match regex 1, or regex 2, but it does match regex 3. So the best fit is regex 3, even though it would have matched regex 4 if it had gotten that far.

Of course this depends on the regexes that you're using, and you'll have to decide for yourself how to order your regexes.